Border bottom in tr table only if condition is verified
As already indicated in the title, I want to add a bottom border on the row only if the date in the row IS DIFFERENT from the row below.
Below is my code; as you can see I added the condition in the tr but it is not working for me


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.6.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-Kc323vGBEqzTmouAECnVceyQqyqdsSiqLQISBL29aUW4U/M7pSPA/gEUZQqv1cwx4OnYxTxve5UMg5GT6L4JJg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-v2CJ7UaYy4JwqLDIrZUI/4hqeoQieOmAZNXBeQyjo21dadnwR+8ZaIJVT8EE2iyI61OV8e6M8PP2/4hpQINQ/g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.1.3/css/dataTables.dataTables.css" />
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.1.3/js/dataTables.js"></script>

</head>
<style>
    tr.border_bottom td {
        border-bottom: 3px solid black;
    }
</style>

<body>
        <table id="myTable" class="display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Category</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach($announcements as $key=>$announcement)
            <tr class="@if($announcements[$key]->date != $announcements[$key+1]->date) border_bottom @endif">
                <td>{{$announcement->title}}</td>
                <td>{{$announcement->date}}</td>
                <td>{{$announcement->category->name}}</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>

</body>
<script>
    let table = new DataTable('#myTable', {
        order: [
            [1, 'asc']
        ]
    });
</script>

</html>



PS: See the code below to understand!


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.6.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-Kc323vGBEqzTmouAECnVceyQqyqdsSiqLQISBL29aUW4U/M7pSPA/gEUZQqv1cwx4OnYxTxve5UMg5GT6L4JJg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-v2CJ7UaYy4JwqLDIrZUI/4hqeoQieOmAZNXBeQyjo21dadnwR+8ZaIJVT8EE2iyI61OV8e6M8PP2/4hpQINQ/g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.1.3/css/dataTables.dataTables.css" />
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.1.3/js/dataTables.js"></script>

</head>
<style>
    tr.border_bottom td {
        border-bottom: 3px solid black;
    }
</style>

<body>
        <table id="myTable" class="display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Category</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="">
                <td>Lamborghini Urus</td>
                <td>2024-08-01</td>
                <td>Motori</td>
            </tr><tr class="">
                <td>CONSOLE SONY PLAYSTATION 5 STANDARD EDITION + GOD OF WAR RAGNAROCK VCH EU</td>
                <td>2024-08-01</td>
                <td>Motori</td>
            </tr><tr class="">
                <td>Kawasaki Ninja H2 SX SE</td>
                <td>2024-08-11</td>
                <td>Motori</td>
            </tr><tr class="">
                <td>HP ZBook Fury 17 G7 119W4-D3 17,3" UHD 4K DC i9-10885H 128 GB 2x2 TB RTX3000 W10P</td>
                <td>2024-08-15</td>
                <td>Libri</td>
            </tr></tbody>
    </table>

</body>
<script>
    let table = new DataTable('#myTable', {
        order: [
            [1, 'asc']
        ]
    });
</script>

</html>



Suppose we have the table produced by the following code; what I want is insert:

a border bottom on the second row (since 2024-08-01 is different from 2024-08-11),
a border bottom on the third row (since 2024-08-11 is different from 2024-08-15).

Can someone help me do this please?

So is there an issue with your current code? Other than running into an undefined index error in $announcements[$key+1], I don't see any immediate problems. Please edit the question to add what the issue is with your current code

Your condition looks correct, but I think changing your approach slightly will make it work better.

Add a check to ensure the next row exists.
Assign the condition to a variable and use that variable in a ternary operator to add the border_bottom class.

I converted your code to a simple PHP script and made these changes, and it worked:
<?php
$announcements = [
    ['date' => '2023-08-01', 'title' => 'John Doe'],
    ['date' => '2023-08-01', 'title' => 'Jane Smith'],
    ['date' => '2023-08-02', 'title' => 'Alice Johnson'],
    ['date' => '2023-08-03', 'title' => 'Bob Brown'],
];

foreach ($announcements as $key => $announcement) :
    $isDifferentDate = isset($announcements[$key + 1]) && $announcement['date'] !== $announcements[$key + 1]['date'];
?>
    <tr class="<?= $isDifferentDate ? 'border_bottom' : '' ?>">
        <td><?= $announcement['title'] ?></td>
        <td><?= $announcement['date'] ?></td>
        <td>{{$announcement->category->name}}</td>
    </tr>
<?php
endforeach;
?>

Output:

I have made some changes to your code for clarity and ease, according to my understanding, without testing it in Laravel. I think it will work:
@foreach($announcements as $key => $announcement)
    @php
        $nextAnnouncement = $announcements[$key + 1] ?? null;
        $shouldAddBorder = $nextAnnouncement && $announcement->date != $nextAnnouncement->date;
    @endphp
    <tr class="{{ $shouldAddBorder ? 'border_bottom' : '' }}">
        <td>{{ $announcement->title }}</td>
        <td>{{ $announcement->date }}</td>
        <td>{{ $announcement->category->name }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach

